# 2077 Honda CRV, new battery, clicking noise

Tags: honda, noise, crv

I just had the battery changed.  They hooked up a 'brain saver' to the OBD to save the computer while the battery is being switched.  First time that's ever been done to my knowledge.  Anyway, new battery, car starts fine.  Then this clicking noise starts up. Like the sound a car makes when you have a turn signal on.  It'll stop when I get about 40 mph but start back when I tap the brake, etc.  Will also keep going if the car is idling.  So it's def electrical and it's coming from the dash area (not the radio/CD).  The auto parts place can't figure out what is going on, naturally.  Any ideas as it'll be driving me crazy.   Thinking about disconnecting the new battery for about 10 seconds and see if something resets.  Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I doubt this has anything to do with the battery being changed. I'd bet it's a problem with the motors which run your dash gauges (most likely the speedo). Is this actually a 2007 CR-V?

Comment: @Paulster2 I thought the 2077 models had the flux capacitor drive...

Comment: is it one of the heater flap motors? is it set on recirculate?

Comment: @SolarMike - Ah ... I think you're right! My bad :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 re flux capacitor - was only to make you smile :)

Comment: @Solar Mike There are pills to help capacitor re flux.  Cut down on the spicy fuel, especially before night drives.